# can someone explain how javascript sort method works?

Tags: javascript

I have encountered this javascript code involving a `sort` method with a custom return.

```
const nums =  ['9', '5', '3', '34', '30' ];
const num = nums.map(n => n.toString()).sort((a,b) => a + b < b + a? 1: -1).join('')
```

Essentially, this code is returning the largest possible integer.  I have the basic knowledge of sort, if you want the numbers in ascending order then you'll use `a-b` for the return.  If descending is desired, then you would use `b-a`.

I want to know how the `a` and `b` are working behind the scenes.  I couldn't find a source where it explains in details how the sort works. I would like to know step by step when the `sort` is in action; it will give me a better a idea how the code above works.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: The following links should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: what is nums? i s it arr?

Comment: Your compare callback doesn't make any sense. The return value will always be `-1`

Comment: In this case `a + b` is string concatenation not arithmetical operation and the sort function is ordering the elements alphabetically not numerically (`111` will be before `2`)

Comment: Ah, right... concatenation, not addition. That was really bugging me.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Not always. For instance, when `a` is `'5'` and `b` is `'9'`, it returns 1 because `'59' < '95'` is true.

Comment: As an aside, it looks like this code snippet is actually designed to take a list of integers (rather than strings), which is probably why the `map()` method is there.

Answer (score 1):

Details can be found [in the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort). Basically, `sort` works by calling the callback repeated to compare two entries from the array. The callback is supposed to return -1 if `a` is "less than" `b` (according to whatever rules that particular callback wants to apply for what "less than" means), 0 if they're the same, or 1 if `a` is "greater than" `b`. It continues doing that, with different pairs of entries from the array, until it's sorted the array.

**How** `sort` does that is up to the implementation, it's not dictated in the spec. All the spec dictates is the paragraph above, and that (as of quite recently) the sort must be stable.

A couple of notes on the specific code you've shown:

- `arr` should be `nums` in the first line
- There's no point to the `map` call, the entries in the array are already strings
- The comparisons it's doing are alphabetic
- The `sort` method is incorrectly coded, because if `a` and `b` are the same, it returns -1, not 0

Comment: Didn't know the specification was updated to require stability in the implementation, nice detail.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Thanks. :-) Writing [my book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1119367956), I have to be fairly clued in to changes. :-)

Comment: (I might actually suggest that book as my next Christmas gift, hope you can get it published before then **edit** January 9th... maybe a late Christmas gift then)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Yeah, I blew it on making it in time for Christmas. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You yould take a little different callback which adds the two values in different order and returns the delta of both.

It works by getting a part string of the final result and changes the order for getting the greatest value of both items.

> For example, the given data sorts in EDGE in this order:
>
> ```
>  a   b  b + a  a + b  delta  comment       array
> --  --  -----  -----  -----  -------  --------------
>                                        3  5  9 30 34
>  3   5     53     35    -18  switch    5  3  9 30 34
>  3   9     93     39    -54  switch    5  9  3 30 34
>  5   9     95     59    -36  switch    9  5  3 30 34
>  3  30    303    330     27  keep      9  5  3 30 34
> 30  34   3430   3034   -396  switch    9  5  3 34 30
>  5  34    345    534    189  keep      9  5  3 34 30
>  3  34    343    334     -9  switch    9  5 34  3 30
> ```

```js
const
    array = ['3', '5', '9', '30', '34'],
    result = array.sort((a, b) => (b + a) - (a + b)).join('');

console.log(...array);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for providing the example, i like visual explanations.  The one thing I'm still puzzled.  So you go from `3` to `5`, then `3` to `9`, but I'm not sure why you went from `5` to `9` instead of from `3` to `30`.

Comment: it is not me, it is the implementation which is not defined in the language specification (ECMA Script). the vendor of the user agent puts it's own algorithm for sorting.